# Magento Grid - sortering and filtering works incorrectly after joining flat table to EAV

Tags: magento

I have 2 custom colletions. Usual collections with flat data.
I need to join them to customers select. It works fine with innerJoin, but filtering and sorting for joined fields doesn't work. How can I solve this?

_prepareCollection() example

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('customer/customer_collection')
    ->addNameToSelect()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('email');

$collection
    ->getSelect()
    ->joinInner(array('my_table' => $collection->getTable('my/table')), 'e.entity_id = my_table.customer_id', array('custom_field' => my_table.custom_field))
    ->joinInner(array('my_table1' => $collection->getTable('my/table1')), 'my_table1.other_id = my_table.id', array('custom_field1' => my_table1.custom_field));

$this->setCollection($collection);
return parent::_prepareCollection();
```

So, sorting and filtering will not work for custom_field and custom_field1

Add column call:

```
$this->addColumn('custom_field',
        array(
            'header'=>$this->__('Shopping club name'),
            'index'=>'custom_field',
            'filter_index'=>'my_table.custom_field',
    ));
```

While filtering I get fatal error:

```
Call to a member function getBackend() on a non-object
```

Sorting doesn't work, no errors shown

'filter_index' works fine if you join flat to flat tables. But here flat is joined to EAV.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This isn't too hard at all actually!

When I did this I was adding the last_login to the customer grid.

The first step, which you have already done but I'm including here for completeness, is to add the column to the initial select statement:

```
/**
 * set collection object
 *
 * @param Mage_Customer_Model_Resource_Customer_Collection $collection
 */
public function setCollection($collection)
{
    //Group by email since multiple customer_ids can exist in the log/customer.
    $collection->groupByEmail();

    //join the last_login field here.
    $collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(array('c_log' => $collection->getTable('log/customer')), 'c_log.customer_id=e.entity_id', array('last_login' => 'login_at'));

    parent::setCollection($collection);
}
```

Next, we add the column to the grid.  Notice we are defining two callbacks.  'filter_condition_callback' is stock Magento.  Oddly, there is no callback index (so far as I am aware) to sort on this.  We need to add a sort callback otherwise we can't sort our new column.

```
    $this->addColumnAfter('last_login', array(
         'header'                    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Last Login'),
         'type'                      => 'datetime',
         'align'                     => 'center',
         'index'                     => 'last_login',
         'filter_index'              => '`c_log`.`login_at`',
         'gmtoffset'                 => true,
         //Stock Magento Callback - Notice the callback key has been assigned.
         'filter_condition_callback' => 'filter_last_login',
         //Custom Callback Index
         'order_callback'            => 'sort_last_login'
    ), 'customer_since');
```

Next, we add the callback functions that will handle the filtering & sorting:

```
if (!function_exists('filter_last_login')) {
    /**
     * @param Mage_Customer_Model_Resource_Customer_Collection $collection
     * @param Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column          $column
     */
    function filter_last_login($collection, $column)
    {
        if (!$column->getFilter()->getCondition()) {
            return;
        }

        $condition = $collection->getConnection()
            ->prepareSqlCondition('c_log.login_at', $column->getFilter()->getCondition());
        $collection->getSelect()->where($condition);
    }
}

if (!function_exists('sort_last_login')) {
    /**
     * @param Mage_Customer_Model_Resource_Customer_Collection $collection
     * @param Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column          $column
     */
    function sort_last_login($collection, $column)
    {
        $collection->getSelect()->order($column->getIndex() . ' ' . strtoupper($column->getDir()));
    }
}
```

Finally, since the order_callback is not a real index we need to call this callback if defined instead of the default sorting mechanism.  This is how i accomplished it:

```
/**
 * Sets sorting order by some column
 *
 * @param Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column $column
 *
 * @return Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid
 */
protected function _setCollectionOrder($column)
{
    if ($column->getOrderCallback()) {
        call_user_func($column->getOrderCallback(), $this->getCollection(), $column);

        return $this;
    }

    return parent::_setCollectionOrder($column);
}
```

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Works brilliantly! Sorting is awesome! Thanks!

Comment: Maybe need some changes:
          'filter_condition_callback' => array($this, 'filter_last_login'),
          'order_callback'            => array($this, 'sort_last_login')

Comment: The question is rather old so I'm not going to update.  But ya, Hoang's addition is better.  I didn't know about this at the time.  Can define the function inside the collection, much better.

Comment: @HoangLan's addition worked for me, also I had to remove `function_exists` conditions and add `protected` before starting function.

Comment: @Ian I am facing the same issue, I tried all of your suggestions but no luck. can you help me in this regard?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40195213/sales-order-grid-filter-sorting-not-working-in-magento

Answer (score 6):

Could you show a call of addColumn() that adds your attributes to grid?

It should be like:

```
$this->addColumn('custom_field', array(
    ...
    'filter_index' => 'my_table.custom_field',
    ...
));
```

Probably you set the alias value for the 'filter_index' key.

Comment: filter_index works fine if you join flat to flat tables. But here flat is joined to EAV.